# Azure. How to deploy custom file referenced by DSC

Tags: azure, dsc

I'm building an Azure RM Template that will install DSC on a target VM. DSC must use a .bacpac file. How can I upload that file to a target VM? How can I make it to be downloaded by target VM from GitHub and placed on a specific folder?
The DSC configuration looks like this:
https://github.com/PowerShell/xDatabase/blob/dev/Examples/Sample_xDatabase.ps1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration,xPSDesiredStateConfiguration,xDatabase

Node $nodeName
{
    LocalConfigurationManager
    {
        RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
    }

    xRemoteFile BacPacPackage
    {  
        Uri             = "https://github.com/url_to_your_bacpac"
        DestinationPath = "c:\where_to_put_it"
        MatchSource     = $false
    } 

    xDatabase DeployBacPac
    {
        Ensure = "Present"
        SqlServer = $nodeName
        SqlServerVersion = $SqlServerVersion
        DatabaseName = $DatabaseName
        Credentials = $credential # credentials to access SQL
        BacPacPath = "c:\path_from_previous command"
        DependsOn = "[xRemoteFile]BacPacPackage"
    }
}
```